# Clojure exception handling

Tags: exception, clojure

I'm having some issues with **clojure.data.xml** in that when parsing bad XML, the exception thrown is not caught. I've found some issues perhaps with run-time wrappers, but my attempts to unwrap it have been unsuccessful can anyone point out to me why this may be happening?

```
(defn parse-xml-from-string
  "takes in valid xml as a string and turns it into 
   #clojure.data.xml data, if bad xml returns false"
  [xml]
  (try
    (do (parse (java.io.StringReader. xml)))
    (catch javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException e false)
    (catch Exception ex
      (cond (isa? (class (.getCause ex)) javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException) false))))
```

method call

```
(viva-api.helpers.validation/parse-xml-from-string "<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><foo><bar><baz>The baz value</baz></bar></foos>")
```

output

```
#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :foo, :attrs {}, :content (user=> XMLStreamException  ParseError at [row,col]:[1,84]
Message: The end-tag for element type "foo" must end with a '>' delimiter.  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next (XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to catch the exception twice? Also the (do) block is not necessary with only one expression inside.

Comment: edited to show input/output. the reason for the two catches is to show what I had found as possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you are seeing is related to the laziness of the value returned by `parse`. According to its [docstring](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/xml.clj#L328) *"Parses the source, which can be an InputStream or Reader, and **returns a lazy tree** of Element records. [...]"*.

```
(ns xml
  (:use clojure.data.xml))

(defn parse-xml-from-string
  "takes in valid xml as a string and turns it into 
   #clojure.data.xml data, if bad xml returns false"
  [xml]
  (try
    (parse (java.io.StringReader. xml))
    (catch javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException ex
      false)))

(parse-xml-from-string "<bla/>") ;= #clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :bla, :attrs {}, :content ()}

(parse-xml-from-string "<bla") ;= false

(parse-xml-from-string "<bla>") ; throws XMLStreamException

(def x (parse-xml-from-string "<bla>")) ; doesn't throw an exception unless it's evaluated

x ; throws XMLStreamException
```

---

**EDIT**

The value returned from `parse` is a lazy tree built top-down from an `Element` record and based on a lazy sequence of `Event` objects, as mentioned in the [docstring](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/xml.clj#L178) for the `event-tree` function. The laziness lies in the `:content` field of the record which is realized when the field is accessed. One way I've found to force the realization of the whole tree is using the `str` function, this feels hacky and looks ugly but anyone who has a better idea can provide a better solution.

```
(defn parse-xml-from-string
  "takes in valid xml as a string and turns it into 
   #clojure.data.xml data, if bad xml returns false"
  [xml]
  (try
    (let [x (parse-str xml)]
      (str x)
      x)
    (catch javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException ex
      false)))
```

This seems like going to great lengths to avoid laziness which is, as I understand it, one of the main reasons to use `clojure.data.xml`. Since you seem to want your whole XML string parsed at once maybe the `clojure.xml/parse` function is better suited for your needs.

```
(defn my-parse-str
  [s]
  (try
    (xml/parse (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. (.getBytes s)))
    (catch Exception e false)))
```

Comment: In that case he should replace his do with doall.

Comment: with doall I get this output

XMLStreamException ParseError at [row,col]:[1,84]
Message: The end-tag for element type "foo" must end with a '>' delimiter.  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next (XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
#clojure.data.xml.Element{:tag :foo, :attrs {}, :content (user=>

Comment: @user1944838 I've tried using `doall` but it doesn't work, the data structure returned by `parse` is not a simple lazy sequence.

Comment: but it is a lazy tree

Comment: @ChadJPetersen Just edited the answer with a possible workaround and some comments.

Comment: @juan.facorro while that does still work when the string is correct. It still wont catch the exception on a malformed XML string.